# How to read the one-to-many mapping between 2 entities

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

These are examples taken from Java Persistence With Hibernate (Manning). I am confused about 2 examples in the book

[image]

In this case, ONE user can have MANY billing details. However only one of the billing details is the default and hence user has a single defaultBilling variable.

With regard to this, why is that we are mapping using @ManyToOne and not @OneToMany? How do I read these? I was under the impression that the mapping in the user class was to be read from the User and moving to BillingDetails. Hence I expected to see @OneToMany (reading it as ONE user has MANY billing details.)

Moving ahead , in another example in the book

[image]

The change here is the we are storing all the billing details (instead of a single default billing details) for each user. In this case I see the @OneToMany annotation which is inline with my expectation

Can any elaborate how the first example uses the converse mapping? Or is that an errata in the book?

Answer (score 0):

The following mappings:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @ManyToOne
  private BillingDetails;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Collection<BillingDetails> billingDetails;
}
```

tell you that a user can have multiple billing details but only one of them is the default one. This is a valid combination, so what you are describing are actually two different use cases.

The alternative is to remove the `@ManyToOne` association and to add a new property/column to `BillingDetails` itself which would contain the information whether the billing is the default one for the user it belongs to, but it has two disadvantages compared to keeping that information in the `User`:

1. When changing the default billing details, you have to update two rows in the `BillingDetails` table, one to clear the old default and another to set the default to.
2. When obtaining the default billing details for a user, you would iterate over the collection of all billing details for the user, or you would need to implement a separate query to fetch it.